# CSV file is opened as binary file in CentOS

Tags: csv, centos, binaryfiles, winscp

I have a `add.csv` file with 5 thousand mobile numbers.

**add.csv in Windows Server**

```
929000213816
929000228777
929000289851
929000358597
.
.
.
xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

When I transfer this file to CentOS server with WinSCP, it becomes like this:

**add.csv in CentOS Server**

```
<FF><FE>9^@2^@9^@0^@0^@0^@2^@1^@3^@8^@1^@6^@^M^@
^@9^@2^@9^@0^@0^@0^@2^@2^@8^@7^@7^@7^@^M^@
^@9^@2^@9^@0^@0^@0^@2^@8^@9^@8^@5^@1^@^M^@
^@9^@2^@9^@0^@0^@0^@3^@5^@8^@5^@9^@7^@^M^@
.
.
.
^@x^@x^@x^@x^@x^@x^@x^@x^@x^@x^@x^@x^@^M^@
```

When I try to open it with **less** or **vi**, it gives following message:

```
less add.csv
"add.csv" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?
```

How can I have the CSV file in correct content on CentOS?

Comment: I'm not sure this is related to programming and thus, it's off-topic here. I tried to clean-up the question and flag this to be migrated to [su] instead.

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes andrew, this is not related to programming. I am using this file in my program. Do you have any idea what is causing it to turn into binary?

Comment: No, I don't have any idea, but this is off-topic here, and hence I hope it'll be migrated to [su], which is the better site for using applications/tools on PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<FF> <FE>` is a BOM (Byte Order Mark) for a 16-bit `Unicode` file.

Whatever aplication you used to create `add.csv` is creating `Unicode` files - you presumably need to change its settings so it outputs regular `ASCII`.

Comment: Yes you are right. The application I was using was creating **Unicode** files. Now I changed the settings and its working fine :)